# Trouble passing links from one function to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I've written a very small script in `node.js` using `request` and `cheerio` to parse `titles` connected to `links` which I've already scraped from it's landing page.

The problem is I can't find any idea as to how I can pass links (populated from the first function) to the second function in order to get the titles from there. I'm very new to `node.js` so can't figure out how to return the result from the first function and pass them to the latter one.

The error I'm having:

```
for (const link of links) {
                   ^
ReferenceError: links is not defined
```

This is the full script:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com';

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.title .storylink').each(function(){
    var links = $(this).attr("href");
    });
  }
});

for (const link of links) {
  (function(url) {
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var title = $('title').eq(0).text();
        console.log(title);
      }
    });
})(link);
}
```

Btw, the selectors used within the script are flawless. All I need to know is pass the result from one function to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found myself a solution. It did the trick:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com';

function getItems(callback){
  request(url, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $('.title .storylink').each(function(){
      var links = $(this).attr("href");
      return callback(links,false);
      });
    }
  });
}
getItems((link)=>{
    request(link, function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var title = $('title').eq(0).text();
        console.log(title);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'links' var is out of scope.  It is outside the callback in 'request'.   Either have to turn request into a promise, use request-promise, or move the for loop into the function to keep links in scope.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async